# VMware Player installs but then I cant find it on my machine

Tags: ubuntu, vmware

I am running ubuntu 11.10 and installed VMware Player following [this](http://debianhelp.wordpress.com/2011/11/22/how-to-install-vmware-player-in-ubuntu/) tutorial and at the end I get a successful install window but then when I close that and try to find VMware on my machine it isn't there...What in the world am I missing? Has anyone run into this?

[image: This is the successful install message I get]

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded VIX instead of Player. wupz. :/